# Multiple files, same name

Tags: c#, scripting, copy

I am trying to save a few files that all have the same name. I want to do something where the names do something like this: file.extension file[1].extension file[2].extension I have tried this http://www.naspinski.net/post/Saving-multiple-files-of-the-same-name.aspx but it didn't work for me.

here is some code to look at(not the entire thing, just the relevant parts),

```
        {
            string thepathoflife = Path.GetFullPath(file);
            //CreatetheFolder(file)
            string filetocopy = file;
            object bob = file.Clone();
            string bobby = bob.ToString();
            string location = file;
            bool b = false;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
            string thenameofdoom = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
            ////bobby.Move(@"\\TEST12CVG\Public\Posts\Temporaryjunk" + filename);
            // string oldlocation = filename+extension;

            if (extension == ".pst" ||
              extension == ".tec" ||
              extension == ".pas" ||
              extension == ".snc" ||
              extension == ".cst" ||
              extension == ".xml")
            {
                b = true;
            }

            if (thenameofdoom == "Plasma" ||
              thenameofdoom == "Oxygas" ||
              thenameofdoom == "plasma" ||
              thenameofdoom == "oxygas" ||
              thenameofdoom == "Oxyfuel" ||
              thenameofdoom == "oxyfuel")
            {
                b = false;
            }


            if (b == true)
            // System.IO.File.WriteAllText(newlocation, bobby);
            {
                //string rootpath = (@"\\sigmatek.net\Documents\Customers\A");
                var findLevel = 6;
                var path = @thepathoflife;
                var levels = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                var second = levels.Length > findLevel ? levels[findLevel] : null;

                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\TEST12CVG\Public\Posts\Test\" + thenameofdoom);
                string newlocation = (@"\\TEST12CVG\Public\Posts\Test\" + thenameofdoom);
                string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(newlocation, second);
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
                string newlocationb = Path.GetFullPath(newPath);

                    string newb = System.IO.Path.Combine(newlocationb, filename);

                        while (File.Exists(newb))
                            {
                               int number = 1;
                               bool found = false;
                               do
                               {
                                   string candidate = newb.Replace(extension, "[" + number++ + "]"+ extension);
                                   if (!File.Exists(candidate)) found = true;

                                {
                                    File.Copy(thepathoflife, candidate);
                              }
                                   // Candidate has a valid file name


                               }
                               }
                    //File.Move(@"\\TEST12CVG\Public\Posts\Test\", @"\\TEST12CVG\Public\Posts\Test\" + thenameofdoom + second);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Success: " + filename + "--" + thepathoflife);
                    b = false;
```

Comment: I do not have any code to share, mainly because it was full of exceptions and crap that makes me mad.

Comment: So exactly what is your question?

Comment: I want to make the files save, without losing them, there will be about 400 different folders with about 20 different files in each of them, so I can't do it manually.

Comment: Where do you have these files? In some array, like FileInfo[]?

Comment: everything I tried made the thing spit out errors that made no sense, like at the end of the script I had a } it was saying I needed a ),;, and while around it.

Comment: I mean random crap that would cause the script to fail harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is off the top of my head.  Also, if ".extension" occurs somewhere in the filename other than at the end, this would break (so make your string handling a bit smarter than the sample code).  If needed, you can get the extension using `Path.GetExtension(path)`

```
if (File.Exists(fn))
{
   int number = 1;
   bool found = false;
   do
   {
       string candidate = fn.Replace(".extension", "[" + number++ + "].extension");
       if (!File.Exists(candidate)) found = true;
   }
   // Candidate has a valid file name
}
```

Comment: I'll try it, this is to fill up the minimum of 15 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in "*sPathAndFileName*" and use the outputted "*sSaveName*" to save your file.
You will see friendly incremented file names like: Test.txt, Text[1].txt, Test[2].txt, etc...

```
    int index = 0;
    string sSaveName = Path.GetDirectoryName(sPathAndFileName) + @"\"
                     + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sPathAndFileName)
                     + Path.GetExtension(sPathAndFileName);
    while (File.Exists(sSaveName) == true)
    {
        sSaveName = Path.GetDirectoryName(sPathAndFileName) + @"\"
                  + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sPathAndFileName)
                  + "[" + (++index).ToString() + "]"
                  + Path.GetExtension(sPathAndFileName);
    }
```

Comment: I forget exactly why I did this (maybe to deliberately error out while parsing out a bad filename), but you could make this code even more simple by changing the sSaveName declaration to this: string sSaveName = sPathAndFileName;

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Much simplier.

```
string filename = "C:\bla.txt";
string filenameNoPath = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
string temppath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
     File.WriteAllBytes(filename, file);
}
else
{
     do
     {
           counter++; // we're here, so lets count files with same name
           string path = temppath + "\\" + filenameNoPath + "(" + counter.ToString() + ")" + extension;
     } while (File.Exists(path));

     File.WriteAllBytes(path, file);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use the  `Path.GetExtension(string path)` in order to get the extension of the file and after that just cut the filename append the iteration number on it and extension again.

Answer (score 0):

You can not put files with the same name and extension in the same folder, so you have an options like:

- put them all in seprate directories wih meaningful names (even if files have a same name the content *should* be digferent)
- use date time stamp in front, like YYYYMMDD in front of every file (but it violates the "same file name" rule)
- the same can be applied to extensions

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but feel I did this too many times over the years. :)

Try something along these lines:

```
        List<string> filesToSave = new List<string>();
        var fileName = "myfile.ext";
        var baseName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

        int counter = 1;
        foreach (var fileToSave in filesToSave)
        {
            var tempFileName = fileName;
            while (File.Exists(tempFileName))
            {
                tempFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}.{2}", baseName, counter, extension);
                counter++
            }

            File.WriteAllText(tempFileName, fileToSave);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can help your self:

```
        string[] files = { "file.txt", "file.txt", "file.txt" };
        for(int i=0;i<files.Length;i++)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i]);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i]);
            fileName = fileName + (i + 1);
            //if you would like to aqdd square brackets, you can change upper line to:
            fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", fileName, "[", (i + 1), "]");
            files[i] = String.Concat(fileName, extension);
        }
```

Same you can do, if you have files in FileInfo array.