# How to store videos for a website?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, video

I am developing an ASP.NET website. In the website users needs to create an account and then they can upload videos of their work. Viewers can view it freely. I use html5 `<video>` tag to display videos. I am using sql server database. Now where to store the videos when the user uploads it? Should I store all the videos in same folder? If yes then there can be multiple videos of same name. How to deal with that?

Comment: /videos/username/uploaded_vid ?

Comment: is it a good idea to store video in your own folders ( probably no), do you have enough space ?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to embed an id in the name, one way or another.

You can prefix it like this

343-Video.mp4, 344-Video.mp4, 345-How to make a sandwich.mp4

Or you can replace the entire thing with a guid and store all information in the database.

If you go with the guid, I would personally store all the videos in the same folder out of convinience, to make retrieval as simple as possible. A problem with this is SEO, search engines love file names and they don't like IDs in the names.

To get file names, you can either make folders and name them the IDs and put the videos in there or you can make a controller that will serve the files from an id. The simplests of those is by far to have folders with IDs as the names then have the videos in there, you can also fittingly store the same video of different formats in there.

/videos/343/How to make a sandwich.mp4, /videos/343/How to make a sandwich.webm

/videos/344/video.mp4, /videos/344/video.webm

That is if you have plenty of storage and want to use your own server, otherwise you can save a lot of server costs(Both storage and trafic) by using a service to host your videos, e.g. YouTube or Vimeo

Comment: About the note about SEO and seperating the ID from the name, I would say StackOverflow shows up in quite often in my searches and have a look at their URL

Comment: I would probably store the video on server because I don't want it to be available somewhere else as some of it would be paid. I might use Google cloud engine for that

Answer (score 0):

You would want to tag the videos with some kind of ID associated with them, especially if they might have the same name.  Basically, you'll store a record in a table that contains the information (who uploaded, upload date, video type, etc.) for the upload.  You'll also want to store the path to the actual file on the file server where you're storing the videos and then use that path to view them.

Comment: I have the ID in my database but what about the folder where I am storing. It wont allow storing videos with same name I guess.

Comment: Does the user have the option to change the name of the file being uploaded?  You could always throw an error and prompt them to change the name before the file is uploaded.

Comment: This thread seems to have some insight:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356458/multiple-files-same-name

Comment: I don't think it would be a valid option to ask user to change the file name

Answer (score 0):

upload videos in each user's folder or assign a random unique name to videos (like Guid) then add a row to the database indicating the actual name and folder of video file.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer for filename coding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1638761/844044

In SQL you keep a link between original filename (or the name you want to display) and the base64 filename you generate.

There might be collisions on the base64 filename you generate (this should be randomly generated) but that would be trivial to solve.

also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8, on the youtube filename